# Hibernate/JPA vs JDBC performance

Tags: performance, hibernate, jpa, jdbc

We are using JPA/Hibernate for project where we need to insert, say 10000 records in database with multiple joins/relations etc. The functionality is fine but the performance is really slow.

Just wondering if migrating to JDBC will help in some *performance* gain?

Thanks,
-csn

Comment: Related question: [Hibernate and JDBC performance?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17150085/hibernate-and-jdbc-performance).

Answer (score 5):

You can do *batch inserts* with JPA/Hibernate - see ["Batch processing"](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/batch.html).

You would almost certainly get better performance by doing batch inserts in JDBC (`addBatch()`, etc), but the Hibernate method may be more desirable if your schema is complex.

If you use JDBC batches, make sure that you do all of your `addBatch()` calls in a [*transaction*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_transaction).

If you happen to be using MySQL, be sure to add  `rewriteBatchedStatements=true` to your connection parameters.