# Hibernate and JDBC performance?

Tags: java, hibernate, jdbc

Currently i am switching my java web application from JDBC to Hibernate, in my current implementation with JDBC i load up static data on initialization of the application into static variables so i don't have to directly access the database every time i need some static data, now switching to hibernate i am thinking of getting rid of these static variables as as far as i have researched hibernate keeps loaded data in a cache.

I am fairly new to hibernate so i am not sure if switching from my current method to hibernate will give any performance improvements. I am  going to research further into hibernates caching and run some performance tests to see which method is better but would just like some opinions on what others think regarding performance on both these methods.

Thanks.

Comment: Opinion are [off-topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) for this site.

Comment: What is your reason for changing from JDBC to Hibernate?  In terms of performance, well written JDBC (with caching) should beat Hibernate every time.  In terms of maintainability, the answer would be... it depends on what kind of queries/database modifications you need...

Comment: If you're mainly interested in the caching capabilities then why not go for ehcache rather than hibernate? On average hibernate authors claim an overhead of 10%.

Comment: @UwePlonus, I would think that looking for help understanding the performance characteristics of commonly used libraries is on-topic for this site.

Comment: performance improvements no; development productivity, maybe yes.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

JDBC will always give *better performance* as compared to Hibernate for most of the database vendors. You can check the comparison made as given in the link below. He concludes that Hibernate is fast when querying tables with less rows else JDBC is way better:
http://phpdao.com/hibernate_vs_jdbc/

Another good performance stats can be found in Hibernate forum discussion at https://forum.hibernate.org/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=931708

It states the following order of performance hit taken due to use of Hibernate (please note that this can be improved by tuning Hibernate to one's needs:

> ```
> Objects: 8 - Hibernate: 10ms / Direct JDBC: 10ms = Ratio: 1.0 
> Objects: 16 - Hibernate: 10ms / Direct JDBC: 0ms = Ratio: Infinity 
> Objects: 64 - Hibernate: 20ms / Direct JDBC: 10ms = Ratio: 2.0 
> Objects: 256 - Hibernate: 150ms / Direct JDBC: 30ms = Ratio: 5.0 
> Objects: 512 - Hibernate: 210ms / Direct JDBC: 40ms = Ratio: 5.25 
> Objects: 1024 - Hibernate: 410ms / Direct JDBC: 70ms = Ratio: 5.857143 
> Objects: 2048 - Hibernate: 681ms / Direct JDBC: 180ms = Ratio: 3.7833333
> ```

The choice of Hibernate over JDBC and SQL queries is not because of the performance, but because of reasons mainly *object persistence* and *database independence* in terms of not writing database specific queries. You can read the following PDF guide to get a better view:

- http://www.mindfiresolutions.com/mindfire/Java_Hibernate_JDBC.pdf

Comment: reporting a measurement without of its uncertainty is meaningless

Answer (score 0):

For your particular situation I would recommend creating your own object that would keep needed static value(s). You can populate it during initialization of your application or when that data is requested for the first time.

As for the comparative perfromance, your best case is that your Hibernate-based data access layer would perfrom as good as JDBC, or the perfromance degradation would not affect overall user expereince. Hibernate is used to speed up development and enhance maintainability, not to get a perfromance edge over JDBC.